# Use WTForms QuerySelectField with Pyramid 1.7's db session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, wtforms

I use wtforms_sqlalchemy in my pyramid apps and define several `QuerySelectField`s.  The query factory uses the imported `DBSession` object to make the query.

```
from wtforms.form import Form
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from myapp.models import DBSession, MyModel

def mymodel_choices():
    choices = DBSession.query(MyModel)
    return choices

class MyForm(Form):
    mymod = QuerySelectField(u'Field', query_factory=mymodel_choices)
```

Pyramid 1.7 introduced a new SQLAlchemy scaffold which attaches the db session object to each request.  Using the new scaffold `mymodel_choices` has to use `request` from my view to access the db session.  The field doesn't have access to the request object though, and doesn't know to call the factory with it.

My idea was to update `query_factory` directly from the view but that doesn't seem to be a logical way to do it.  How can I use `QuerySelectField` when the db session is part of the request object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query_factory` only specifies the *default* query to use, but [`QuerySelectField` will prefer the `query` property if it is set.](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms-sqlalchemy/blob/master/wtforms_sqlalchemy/fields.py#L98)  This is useful for Pyramid, which discourages interacting with `threadlocal` directly.

Change the factory to accept a db session.  Set `query` to the result of calling your factory with the request's db session.

```
def mymodel_choices(session):
    return session.query(MyModel)

f = MyForm(request.POST)
f.mymod.query = mymodel_choices(request.db_session)
```

Since this is a bit inconvenient, you can create a subclass of `Form` that takes the `request`, pulls out the appropriate form data, and calls each `QuerySelectField's` query factory with the request.

```
class PyramidForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, request, **kwargs):
        if 'formdata' not in kwargs and request.method == 'POST':
            kwargs['formdata'] = request.POST

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        for field in self:
            if isinstance(field, QuerySelectField) and field.query_factory is not None and field.query is None:
                field.query = field.query_factory(request.db_session)

class MyForm(PyramidForm):
    ...

f = MyForm(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (although it's not the cleanest solution)

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
from pyramid import threadlocal

def mymodel_choices(request=None):
    request = request or threadlocal.get_current_request()
    choices = request.DBSession.query(MyModel)
    return choices
```

for more details please see: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/threadlocal.html

Comment: I've already checked that priority but the documentation says it's a possibility to avoid and users should just use it for testing. Thanks anyway

Comment: @JérômePigeot I believe wtforms is not really designed for this though.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if it's the case, it sounds like a design failure for me. I'm using wtforms but almost all forms libraries will require the same needs. I'll just continue using alchemy's scaffold from the old way :) Thanks